# задача про ООП php

Tags: php, ооп

Задача с одного сайта, найди сумму зарплат двух объектов. $name, $age, $salary объявлены private. Нужно создать функции которые установят имя возраст и зарплату а так же через функции получать значение.
Вот мой код

```
class worker {
    private $name;
    private $age;
    private $salary;

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        echo $this->name;
    }
    public function setAge($age)
    {
        $this->age = $age;
    }
    public function getAge()
    {
        echo $this->age;
    }
    public function setSalary($salary)
    {
        $this->salary = $salary;
    }
    public function getSalary()
    {
        echo $this->salary;
    }
}

$worker1 = new worker;
$worker1->setName("Ivan");
$worker1->setAge(25);
$worker1->setSalary(1000);
$worker2 = new worker;
$worker2->setName("Vasya");
$worker2->setAge(26);
$worker2->setSalary(2000);
$sum = $worker1->getSalary() + $worker2->getSalary();
echo $sum;
```

все устанавливаю но не могу найду сумму зарплат, код выводит 100020000 в конце еще добавляя 0, помогите найди правильную сумму зарплат

Comment: В get - не надо добавлять echo. Эта конструкция печатает на экран вместо того чтобы сделать операции с числами.

Comment: просто оставить $this-salary ? или что?

Comment: @Yanun `return $this->salary`, функция должна возвращать данные, а не печатать на экран

Comment: вместо `echo` напишите `return`

Comment: аааа спасибо, тупую ошибку сделал :Д

Comment: а 0 в конце добавлялся как результат выполнения `echo null+null`

Comment: @radar4ick спасибо

Comment: Ну и вместо кучи кода не лучше ли это делать через конструктор `new worker(name,age,salary);`?

Comment: @InDevX знаю но такой была задача без использование конструктора

Comment: @Yanun ни о чём задача, честно говоря. Сотню лет так учиться будете))

Comment: @InDevX не я быстро прохожу это, больше ради понимания ООП выполняю эти задачи

Comment: @Yanun Такие курсы прошлый век) сугубо моё мнение, да и смысла в них особо нет

Comment: ну сейчас я уставший, но хочу чем то занять себя вот решил задачи выполнить по быстрому.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы используете **echo** в геттерах, а чтобы вернуть значение нужно использовать **return**

```
class worker {
    private $name;
    private $age;
    private $salary;

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
    public function setAge($age)
    {
        $this->age = $age;
    }
    public function getAge()
    {
        return $this->age;
    }
    public function setSalary($salary)
    {
        $this->salary = $salary;
    }
    public function getSalary()
    {
        return $this->salary;
    }
}
```